# How to parse a csv file which contains one line in android

Tags: android, csv

How to parse a csv file which contains one line?
The line elements are separates by semicolon (**;**) and some tags, like `<br>`, `<prg>`, `<qt>`.

Regards

Comment: yes so do you have an idea

Comment: Tou can use the String's `split()` function: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)